# How to get a random string of 32 hexadecimal digits through command line?

Tags: bash, random

I'd like to put together a command that will print out a string of 32 hexadecimal digits. I've got a Python script that works:

```
python -c 'import random ; print "".join(map(lambda t: format(t, "02X"), [random.randrange(256) for x in range(16)]))'
```

This generates output like:

```
6EF6B30F9E557F948C402C89002C7C8A
```

Which is what I need.

On a Mac, I can even do this:

```
uuidgen | tr -d '-'
```

However, I don't have access to the more sophisticated scripting languages ruby and python, and I won't be on a Mac (so no uuidgen). I need to stick with more bash'ish tools like sed, awk, /dev/random because I'm on a limited platform. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `head -c16 </dev/urandom|xxd -p -u`, perhaps?

Comment: @Biffen I find this the most elegant solution of all, more so than any of the answers! I'll be using this, but I'll format it as `head -c 16 /dev/urandom | xxd -p` for improved legibility.

Comment: If you need more than 32 digits, increase the `-c 16` to e.g. `-c 32` and use an `xxd` invocation similar to this: `xxd -p -c 32` (32 = 32 octets (bytes), i.e. 64 hexadecimal characters)

Comment: In other words, like this: `head -c 32 /dev/urandom | xxd -p -c 32`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If you have `hexdump` then:

```
hexdump -vn16 -e'4/4 "%08X" 1 "\n"' /dev/urandom
```

should do the job.

**Explanation:**

- `-v` to print all data (by default `hexdump` replaces repetition by `*`).
- `-n16` to consume 16 bytes of input (32 hex digits = 16 bytes).
- `4/4 "%08X"` to iterate four times, consume 4 bytes per iteration and print the corresponding 32 bits value as 8 hex digits, with leading zeros, if needed.
- `1 "\n"` to end with a single newline.

Comment: @Renauld_Pacalet How would I be able to do the same thing and produce a 32 digit hex like this from a python code. When I do it on command line it works fast 1st time, then after that it takes like 30 seconds or longer for some reason.

Comment: @NormanBird It takes time because `/dev/random` is slow. You cannot read from it with a ultra-high throughput. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819359/dev-random-extremely-slow) explains why. It is not a matter of what language you use. Python would have the same problem. If you do not care too much about the quality of the random generator try `/dev/urandom` instead. But be sure you understand the difference first.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: I suggest you change your answer to use `/dev/urandom`.  To say that it is "lower quality" is a myth.  See https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: @RenaudPacalet then, default to urandom. I have just emptied my entropy pool because of copypasting. I should have reviewed, true, but still, suggesting a solution that consumes this much entropy is not common at all. I strongly suggesto to change your answer example command to urandom (and of course still mention both) .

Comment: use "%08x" for lower case.

Answer (score 121):

If you are looking for a single command and have openssl installed, see below. Generate random 16 bytes (32 hex symbols) and encode in hex (also -base64 is supported).

```
openssl rand -hex 16
```

Comment: Nice, short solution, but it is pseudo-random and uses seed files. It may not be the most secure solution. See: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-rand.html.

Comment: @justinpc that documentation was already outdated when you linked to it. It's good to be aware of the limitation for older installs, but it hasn't applied [since version 1.1.1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-rand.html).

Answer (score 21):

There three ways that I know of:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=16 

# Read n bytes from urandom (in hex):
xxd -l "$n" -p                    /dev/urandom | tr -d " \n" ; echo
od  -vN "$n" -An -tx1             /dev/urandom | tr -d " \n" ; echo
hexdump -vn "$n" -e ' /1 "%02x"'  /dev/urandom ; echo
```

Use one, comment out the other two.

Comment: In my experience `od` is the most common. MacOS had `hexdump`, `xdd`, and `od`. Git Bash (MinGW) had `xxd` and `od`. Docker image based on Alpine Linux had `od` (and `tr` of course). And all three platforms had `/dev/urandom`. So if you are looking for the most portable then stick with the `od` flavor.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
xxd -u -l 16 -p /dev/urandom
```

Example output:

```
C298212CD8B55F2E193FFA16165E95E3
```

And to convert it back to binary:

```
echo -n C298212CD8B55F2E193FFA16165E95E3 | xxd -r -p
```

Answer (score 13):

Here are a few more options, all of which have the nice property of providing an obvious and easy way to directly select the length of the output string. In all the cases below, changing the '32' to your desired string length is all you need to do.

```
#works in bash and busybox, but not in ksh
tr -dc 'A-F0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c32

#works in bash and ksh, but not in busybox
tr -dc 'A-F0-9' < /dev/urandom | dd status=none bs=1 count=32

#works in bash, ksh, AND busybox! w00t!
tr -dc 'A-F0-9' < /dev/urandom | dd bs=1 count=32 2>/dev/null
```

EDIT: Tested in different shells.

Comment: The other ones here all let you specify the length too, except as number of bytes = half the number of characters. And you could easily pipe them into `head -c` to trim it down to an odd number.

Comment: How efficient is your solution compared with `openssl rand -hex 16` ?

Comment: Note: on BSD / macOS you need to set `LC_ALL=C` otherwise tr will try to interpret the input according to your language setting (which will cause `tr: illegal byte sequence`). So the complete command is: `LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-F0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c64`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `od` command like this

```
od -N32 -x < /dev/urandom | head -n1 |  cut -b9- | sed 's/ //gi'
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate output of **arbitrary length, including even/odd number of characters**:

```sh
cat /dev/urandom | hexdump --no-squeezing -e '/1 "%x"' | head -c 31
```

Or to maximize efficiency over readability/composeability:

```
hexdump --no-squeezing -e '/1 "%x"' -n 15 /dev/urandom
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version not using `dev/random`:

```
awk -v len=32 'BEGIN {
    srand('$RANDOM');
    while(len--) {
        n=int(rand()*16);
        printf("%c", n+(n>9 ? 55 : 48));
    };}'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

### Introduction

If your goal is to obtain a *[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variable* and if you want to be quick, and consume less resources, you may want to avoid *forks*. (`var=$(python ..)`)

So the quickest way is to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *builtins*:

From version 5.1, bash present a 32 bits len `$SRANDOM` pseudo random variable:

> ```
>    SRANDOM
>           This variable expands to a 32-bit pseudo-random number  each  time
>           it  is  referenced.  The  random number generator is not linear on
>           systems that support /dev/urandom or arc4random, so each  returned
>           number  has no relationship to the numbers preceding it...
> ```

### Strictly 32 hexadecimal digits.

> random string of 32 hexadecimal digits

You need a bunch of  *`4 x 32 = 128`* bits -> `4` x `$SRANDOM` expansion

```bash
mkrand32(){
    local -n resvar=$1
    local _i _str _part
    resvar=""
    for _i in {1..4};do
         printf -v part '%08x' $SRANDOM
         resvar+=${part}
    done
}
```

This **require** 1 argument: the variable name you want to set:

```bash
mkrand32 varname
echo $varname
d2fd20aad1b9dad4d57c478affa8503e
```

### Same but not limited to 32 digits:

```bash
mkrand () { 
    local -i _i=32 _p
    [[ $1 == -l ]] && _i=$2 && shift 2
    local -n resvar=$1
    local _str _part
    resvar=""
    for ((_p=_i; _p>0; _p-=8)); do
        printf -v part '%08x' $SRANDOM
        resvar+=${part}
    done
    resvar=${resvar::_i}
}
```

Same than previous: default to 32 digits, but could by modified with `-l` switch:

```bash
mkrand test
echo ${#test} $test
32 70105167a19bea5a24c5e36571446f83

mkrand -l 23 test
23 7ce93dd418aacf5bbbaace6
```

```bash
mkrand -l 128 test
echo ${#test} $test
128 5f0707dd58f652f55d048305377be9686d5adaec26176dcedfa1505c457b90b25c13e4a9b61bbe880ad31bca89d3c8d0433f5219cebf159925059318f7047fec
```

**Note:** This don't use `getopts` so `-l` have to be separated to *number of digits* by a space

### Full function with options

You may found on my website (not on github), a [full version of mkrand](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mkrand.bash.txt) ([mkrand.bash](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/mkrand.bash)) source script.

Once loaded:

> ```
> Usage: mkrand [-h] [-a|-d|-x] [-d [-m int]] [-v varname]
>   -h       Show this.
>   -a       Alternative set of 64 chars ( alpha numerics + % + # )
>   -d       Digits only
>   -x       Hexadecimal characters (default)
>   -l int   Length of generated srting (without separators)
>   -m int   Mask for separators (default 0x888800: 1<<23|1<<19|1<<15|1<<11)
>   -s char  Character to be user as separator (default "-")
>   -v name  Variable name to be populated instead of print to STDOUT
> Without argument mkrand will print UUID like 32 hexadecimal string.
>   513ee11e-d6cc-b7b1-8fd9-3462675e93d5
> With `-m 0` or `-s ''`, noseparator will by added.
> Mask for separator is a binary value, used to determine where to insert dash.
> To generate an alpha numeric string of 30 characters, separated every 5 char:
>   mkrand -al30 -m0x1084210 -s' '
>   3PiQo 9RXFn NIi#7 %spWG HREhx wNamf
> A string of 7 bunch of 6 digits, separated by a spaced dash:
>   mkrand -d -l 42 -m 0x820820820 -s ' - '
>   941908 - 240445 - 797528 - 631958 - 635053 - 160422 - 92710
> ```

```bash
mkrand
8eea4296-ffda-ee9a-6fbe-a349c0d7ff18
```

```bash
mkrand -al 54 -m0xaaaaaaaaaaaaa
tF-Zs-r7-bS-3D-AR-m2-S0-GC-lC-SU-k2-Zk-4f-eG-5f-qa-6f-vV-wV-Wc-zA-5Z-dC-Yg-Oz-w6
```

```bash
mkrand -m0
c751eb64b899448a06cf7391d2a009a9
```