# FFmpeg: how to produce MP4 CENC (Common Encryption) videos

Tags: video, encryption, ffmpeg, video-encoding

What is the correct syntax to do CENC encryption with ffmpeg?

The ffmpeg 3.0 release notes include "Common Encryption (CENC) MP4 encoding and decoding support", and the files libavformat/movenccenc.h and  libavformat/movenccenc.c seem to include everything needed to encrypt MP4 files according to the Common Encryption standard.

However, I can't find any documentation on this topic in the ffmpeg manual pages.

Regards

Comment: You mean with the ffmpeg command line interface? If so, this is not a programming question and should be migrated to [su].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mulvya's answer covered the ffmpeg-options.

I'm just adding a concrete example and talk about playback too, as i did some experiments yesterday (independently).

#### Encryption example

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb_encrypted.mp4
```

(of course usage might be different for your case; i just remuxed video and audio)

#### Playback / Decoding

[ffplay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html)

```
ffplay SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb_encrypted.mp4 -decryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb
```

But as this is more or less a prototype-player, one might want to use something more powerful.

[mpv](https://mpv.io/)

```
mpv --demuxer-lavf-o=decryption_key=76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb_encrypted.mp4
```

There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/4579) as my first expected command-line did not behave as expected!

**Edit:** trying to address Reino's questions

The `encryption_key` is just 128 bit = 16 bytes encoded as Hex (following the [usage](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/encryption/common-encryption/) of AES-128-CTR). So [random.org](https://www.random.org/bytes/) with a configuration of 16 bytes and hex.encoding would be a valid key (but i'm not recommending to trust external resources in general). I used python's [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_hex) which boils down to: `secrets.token_hex(16)`. This `encryption_key` will be needed for decoding.

The `encryption_kid` [Key ID](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/index.html#decryption-key-id) is just an identifier for this key, probably needed for more complex usage-patterns (i'm !guessing! you could do something like: *hey video... which of my 1000 keys do i need for you?*). I suppose it's mandatory to pass it, but it's not required for decoding (if you know which key to use for which video).

The official references would be:

- [Standard](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:23001:-7:ed-2:v1:en)
- ffmpeg implementation: docs (available through command-line) or a short [extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943572/)

Comment: I'm new to this whole encryption thing and I'm trying to understand how to generate an encryption key on my own. Can you tell me? Did you use a tool for that perhaps? What exactly is this encryption key identifier? What does it do and is it an obligatory parameter?

Comment: Too bad you don't get e-mail-notification for edited posts, because I only now saw your edited post. Thanks. For Bash https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284034/2703456 did it for me. And it appears even my favorite tool [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) can do it: `xidel -s -e 'random-seed(),string-join((1 to 32) ! x:integer-to-base(random(16),16))'`. The `-encryption_kid`-parameter appears mandatory when encrypting, because you'd get `[mp4 @ 051e28c0] Invalid encryption kid len 0 expected 16` otherwise.

Comment: Note that the CENC flags are not applied when generating DASH. Also I get an error "saio atom found without saiz" when I try to play back the encrypted mp4 with mpv or ffplay - I haven't had time to figure out why yet.

Comment: Just in case anyone runs into this, ffplay/mpv will fail if you use these flags:
`-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof+faststart -frag_duration 2000000`

Comment: In general `encryption_kid` is used for different DRM solutions. 
We pass the `encryption_kid` to the player, the player then passes that `encryption_kid` to a licensing server which then gives the player the key.

DRM (with respect to video playback) tends to mean encrypted video + smart key management

Answer (score 8):

Running `ffmpeg -h muxer=mp4` will produce all the available options for the MP4 muxer, among which are

```
-encryption_scheme <string>     E....... Configures the encryption scheme, allowed values are none, cenc-aes-ctr
-encryption_key    <binary>     E....... The media encryption key (hex)
-encryption_kid    <binary>     E....... The media encryption key identifier (hex)
```

These options and their values should be placed after all the inputs and before the output filename.