# how can i decrypt the encrypted mp4 file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using following command to encrypt the mp4 file having two video tracks and one audio track.

```
fmpeg -i 10M00S.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 10M00S.mp4_enc.mp4
```

How to decrypt the encrypted file and store it with some other name  using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 4):

`ffplay 10M00S.mp4_enc.mp4 -decryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb`

or

`ffmpeg -decryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -i 10M00S.mp4_enc.mp4 \
    [output file options]`

See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949160/4726410).

Comment: can u please clarify more on output file options ? Is it possible to decrypt the encrypted video of particular resolution by specifying resolution ? Decrypted file is not stored because I am not able to get the name of particular file after decryption when i am giving the name of file for streaming. Please clarify above questions.

Comment: Use "-c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2", assuming that's what you want to do. Note that these questions have nothing to do with decryption anymore.