# How can I open a video encrypted with FFMPEG using openCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, encryption, ffmpeg

I am developing a program that encrypts and saves video files and allows them to play only in programs that have key values. (by C#)

I was looking for a way to encrypt a video file and found a way to encrypt it using FFMPEG's CENC.

`ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 SampleVideo_encrypted.mp4`

`ffplay SampleVideo_encrypted.mp4 -decryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb`

`ffmpeg -decryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -i SampleVideo_encrypted.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy SampleVideo_decrypted.mp4`

[FFmpeg: how to produce MP4 CENC (Common Encryption) videos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44939166/22251028)

It is easy to encrypt and makes use of the header information of the video file.

But I couldn't find a way to apply decryption at the same time as the Capture Video of OpenCV.
I thought I could use FFMPEG of OpenCV Backend and set the options, so I found a way to set the Windows environment variable, but it didn't work.(Only the gray screen is output.)
As a result of the search, only options related to H/W acceleration appear in OS environ.

[How to add ffmpeg options to VideoCapture](https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-add-ffmpeg-options-to-videocapture/8972)
(Post written in python)

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "video_codec;h264_cuvid"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
```

Code I tested (not worked, c#)

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS",
                                          "decryption_key;76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb");
VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture(filename, VideoCaptureAPIs.FFMPEG);
...
```

How can I open a video encrypted with FFMPEG using openCV?

Regards.