# Trouble generating random hex numbers using /dev/urandom in bash

Tags: bash, random, hex, xxd

I'm trying to generate a random hex number with an specified length (`$length`) using the following command:

```
head -c $length /dev/urandom | xxd -p -u -c $length | tr -d '[:space:]\\'
```

I've noticed that `head -c $length /dev/urandom` actually prints the double of the `$length` value. So if `$length=1` the output will be 2 characters long. How can I fix this?

Also why does the input number on `xxd -p -u -c $length` seems not to affect on the output? meaning I can use either:

```
head -c 4 /dev/urandom | xxd -p -u -c 20000 | tr -d '[:space:]\\'
```

or

```
head -c 4 /dev/urandom | xxd -p -u -c 4 | tr -d '[:space:]\\'
```

and it will print 8 characters in both cases.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328759/how-to-get-a-random-string-of-32-hexadecimal-digits-through-command-line/34329057#34329057) may help.

Comment: `head -c` designates the number of *bytes*; each byte contains two hex digits; consider generating the hex digits and *then* take the `head -c`, eg: `xxd -p -u /dev/urandom | head -c $length`

Comment: as for the last question ... `head -c 4` is going to send exactly 4 bytes (or 8 hex digits worth) of data to the next command in the pipeline (`xxd` in this case); if `xxd` only has 4 bytes of input to work with then why would you expect it to generate *more* than 8 hex digits worth of output?