# Java Create KeyPair hangs on VM but works on physical system

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

I have some Java code which is creating a KeyPair using JCS and Bouncey Castle.  When I create a keypair on a physical Linux system like my desktop it works fine.  The key generation takes a second or two.  When I run the same code on a VM the key gen usually "hangs" (I leave it running for up to 5 minutes).  Sometimes it works in under 30 seconds but that's rare.

I'm guessing that this has something to do with not enough randomness being available on the VM, but I don't know how to work around this.

Here is the test code which is pulled from my actual program code and condensed:

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class KeyPairCreateTester {
    private static final String RANDOM_ALGO = "SHA1PRNG";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String keyAlgo = "RSA";
        final int keySize = 2048;

        try {
            System.out.printf("Creating random instance using %s\n", RANDOM_ALGO);
            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGO);
            System.out.printf("Creating key using algo %s size %d\n", keyAlgo, keySize);
            KeyPairGenerator keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyAlgo);
            System.out.printf("Initialize\n");
            keygen.initialize(keySize, random);
            System.out.printf("Generating key\n");
            KeyPair keyPair = keygen.generateKeyPair();
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.err.println("No such algo");
        }
    }

}
```

The "hang" occurs after "Generating key".

Adjusting the keySize down to even 512 has only minimal effect.  At 512 the key is generated a few times more often but it still hangs most of the time for at least 5 minutes.

The physical machine and the VM are both Ubuntu 16.04.

Java is 1.8.0_72 + 1.8.0_101 (I tried both).

Would REALLY appreciate some pointers on this one.  It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Most likely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819359/dev-random-extremely-slow

Comment: Yes!  That link does appear to be the same issue.  I installed haveged on my VM and the problem is solved!

Comment: I close this as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem by installing the haveged package and starting that service (systemctl start haveged).